# Top Level Class Instantiation

Tags: c#, oop, layer

I'm fairly new at OOP and seems like everyday I'm learning it the hard way. Me and my team are currently working on a rather big desktop application developet in C# Winforms.

The project I have received from my international colleagues is structured in a 3 Layer application:

- DataLayer
- Domain
- GUI

So far so good, the thing is that in the Domain Layer I have the following classes.

-User.cs
-UserBase.cs

The User.cs is structured this way:

```
/// <summary>
/// Top-level user class.
/// </summary>
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        userBase = new UserBase();
    }

    public IAdmUser userBase { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IAdmGroup> AssGroups { get; set; }

}
```

And the UserBase.cs is structured this way:

```
public class UserBase:ObjectBase, IAdmUser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The date that the user has been registered. The datetime is in UTC format. 
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 0 = User is not Active, 1 = User is Active.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The username.
    /// </summary>
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description of the user.
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Firstname of the user.
    /// </summary>
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Lastname of the user.
    /// </summary>
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Every time I have to use the properties to populate a new object of the type User I have to instantiate it the following way:

```
 var newUser = new User
        {
            userBase =
            {
                FirstName = "name1",
                LastName = "name2",
                Description = "Junior Developer",
                IsActive = true,
                State = ObjectState.Added,
                RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now,
                UserName = "ASD"
            }
        };
```

OR

```
// without object initializer
var newUser = new User()
newUser.userBase.PropertyName = "Assign property value"
```

So basically if I just do: `var user = new User()`, I will not have access to the fields `FirstName, LastName` etc. I have to go down a level like `newUser.userBase.PropertyName`.

I do not understand what is this UserBase.cs, the only thing I have a hunch on is that the `User.cs` is just a Container for the `UserBase.cs`.

I'm requesting help here because the colleague that developed this "framework" has some problems and he's not at work.

Thank you and sorry if this will turn up to be a duplicate post, honestly, I'm not even sure what to ask.

Comment: It looks to me as if the writer didn't understand inheritance in c# too well when first wrote this code, or had a reason not to allow user to inherit from userbase... either way you'll have to wait till your colleague comes back to work or ask people around you

Comment: if user "is a" user base. Use `User : UserBase`. If user "has a" user base your implementation should be ok. May be you need a design pattern which populate the properties for you.

Comment: Having userBase = new UserBase() in the constructor is a pretty big problem.  That's just nonsense, it constructs nothing.   The architect not showing up for work should worry you a great deal.  High odds that *somebody* should say "Stop!" before it spirals into a project disaster.  We can't say it for you, talk to the team members and supervisor.

Comment: Hans, could you explain me a bit more detailed why it's wrong to have `userbase = new UserBase()` in the constructor ?. Without that instantiation I cannot use the properties to create a `User` object.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that this framework was designed with composition in mind. Meaning, that a `User` object is *composed* of various items.

At a DB layer, it might probably be the case you have 2 tables somewhere:

- One for `UserBase` data, which contains information about the users and their accounts.
- One for `IAdmGroup`, which seems to be a collection of groups to which the user belongs.

Both of this information, is probably collated and returned as a single object from your data layer, because by the end of the day, the Domain and GUI *do not care* how is it stored, thus basically, a `User` object will have user information as well as any groups to which it might belong.

To go around your problem of initialisation, you could take a look at `Factory` design patterns. The aim of these patterns is to abstract away object initialization, thus you simply pass along a series of parameters and it is up to the factory to initialize the object.

Other than hiding away initialisation details, this pattern would also allow you some degree of flexibility when it comes to object initialisation, since you could plug in different factories which could initialise different objects.

Thus, your code would look something like this:

```
public static class UserFactory
{
    public static User CreateActiveJuniorDeveloper(string firstName, string lastName, string userName)
    {
         var newUser = new User
            {
                userBase =
                {
                    FirstName = firstName,
                    LastName = lasteName,
                    Description = "Junior Developer",
                    IsActive = true,
                    State = ObjectState.Added,
                    RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now,
                    UserName = userName
                }

                AssGroups = Enumerable.empty<IAdmGroup>();
            };

        return newUser;
    }
}

...

User developerUser = UserFactory.CreateActiveJuniorDeveloper("name1", "name2", "ASD");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your User class needs to inherit from UserBase, like this:

```
public class User : UserBase
```

After this, you can access 'inheritable' properties from the UserBase class as though they were part of the User class.

So instead of setting:

```
User.UserBase.FirstName = "name1";
```

You can use:

```
User.FirstName = "name1";
```

Comment: So, i'm still struggling with this and today's phone call with my superior was not so good. He said that the architect will not be in for work, for at least 2 weeks. *Tears of joy*.

Comment: Did you try to inherit from the base class as I showed?

Comment: Not yet. But everyone said the same thing `User` must inherit from `UserBase`.

Comment: The example I give in my answer IS how you inherit from UserBase. Try it out for yourself.